# How to remove a repository entry from an app that has been removed in Odin

Tags: release-odin

I had installed Grub Customizer and then removed it. I am running Odin.

I get an error when checking for updates in the App Center as follows:

```
The repository 'http//ppa.launchpad.net/-danielrichter 2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu focal release' does not have a release file.
```

From looking at other questions that are similar I see that I need to delete this repository entry. My terminal skills are poor and I am not sure how to do this. Reading other answers isn't helping.

I do not know how to find the entry or how to delete it.

Help anyone!

Rex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this, both are via Terminal and — fortunately — not too complicated.

##### Removing a PPA via `add-apt-repository`

If you added the repository [using the steps from the Launchpad website](https://launchpad.net/%7Edanielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer), then you can remove the reference with a single line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
```

Once removed, update `apt` to ensure everything is good to go:

```
sudo apt update
```

If you installed the PPA through a different method, or if the above command does not work for you, then you'll need to locate the file containing the PPA reference and remove it.

##### Removing a Repository Manually

In Terminal, change your directory to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and list all of the files using `ll`. You should see something like this:

```
$ ll
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 24 13:19 ./
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Sep  9 13:00 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   62 Aug 24 14:18 danielrichter.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  143 Aug 24 13:19 elementary.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  151 Aug 24 13:19 patches.list
```

The `elementary.list` file contains repositories specific to Elementary OS. `patches.list` contains repositories to bug fixes and whatnot. Any other files in this directory will be for software that you installed.

If you're not sure which file has the reference to the `grub-customizer` repository, you can find it with this command:

```
grep -r danielrichter *
```

This will list all files in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory, as well as in any subdirectories.

Now that you've identified which file contains the reference, you have two options:

1. Comment out the repository by adding a `#` to the start of the line. For example, if your `.list` file is named `danielrichter.list`, then you can do this:

   ```
   sudo nano danielrichter.list
   ```

   You may be prompted for your password, as `sudo` is required to edit this file. Once the editor opens, you will see one or two lines inside referencing the PPA that you would like to remove. Add a `#` to the start of the line(s) so that your file looks something like this:

   [image: Nano — Editing]

   Now you can save the file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit, and <kbd>Y</kbd> to save the changes as you exit.

   Once you're out of the file, update `apt` to ensure everything is good to go:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```

   If you ever want to "undo" the PPA removal, simply re-open the file, remove the `#` characters, and update `apt` again. Having lots of `.list` files with commented-out PPAs will not affect system performance.
2. Delete the `.list` file. If you have a file that contains *only* references to the PPA you no longer want, then you can delete it completely like this:

   ```
   sudo rm -f danielrichter.list
   ```

   <sup>**Important:** There is no "undo" when you use `rm`, so be 100% sure you're deleting the correct file.</sup>

   Once the file is deleted, update `apt` to ensure everything is good to go:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```

This long answer may look complicated but, if you sit down and go through the process, I'm sure you'll see it's not too difficult. The first time is always the most stressful

Comment: The first method seems to have worked. Thank you so much for taking the time to help out. I need to continue on my terminal tutorial so I can be more self sufficient. It's wonderful how helpful people are on this forum.

Comment: Be sure to click the little check mark next to the answer if this solved your problem. You can also press the up arrow next to any answer on here if it’s useful 